# Drools if and else based on condition from another rule

Tags: drools

I want to run a rule that calls Java method and passes the fact (or rather, its logical value) from another rule, although I don't know if the java methods are at all important for this problem. It's not easy to describe so I'll try to show it based on an example:

```
rule "Some rule determining fact"

    when
        ... //some conditions
    then
        insert(new SomeCondition(callSomeJavaMethodReturningBoolean()))
    end

rule "Some rule using SomeCondition"

    when
        SomeCondition($value: value)
        ... //some other conditions
    then
        insert(callJavaMethodUsingSomeCondition($value))
    end
```

The problem here is that the first rule doesn't always fire, so `SomeCondition` is not always definded and second rule isn't evaluated.

My second try was to create two separate rules like this:

```
rule "Some rule determining fact"

    when
        ... //some conditions
    then
        insert(new SomeCondition(callSomeJavaMethodReturningBoolean()))
    end

rule "SomeConditionTrueRule"

    when
        SomeCondition(value == true)
        ... //some other conditions
    then
        insert(callJavaMethodUsingSomeCondition(true))
    end

rule "SomeConditionFalseRule"

    when
        not SomeCondition() or SomeCondition(value == false)
        ... //some other conditions
    then
        insert(callJavaMethodUsingSomeCondition(false))
    end
```

This doesn't work as intended either, because it first evaluates `SomeConditionFalseRule` before even evaluating my first rule. I'll appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this problem. Drools version used is `6.5.0` if that matters. Also, I want to avoid using `salience` if possible since I've read it is a bad practice (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to separate the 2 groups of rules (the ones inserting `SomeCondition` objects and the ones executing the java code).

The easiest way would be to use a lower salience in the second group:

```
rule "Some rule determining fact"
when
    ... //some conditions
then
    insert(new SomeCondition(callSomeJavaMethodReturningBoolean()))
end

rule "SomeConditionTrueRule"
salience -1
when
    SomeCondition(value == true)
    ... //some other conditions
then
    insert(callJavaMethodUsingSomeCondition(true))
end

rule "SomeConditionFalseRule"
salience -1
when
    not SomeCondition() or SomeCondition(value == false)
    ... //some other conditions
then
    insert(callJavaMethodUsingSomeCondition(false))
end
```

A more robust approach would be to use 2 `agenda-groups` and to activate them one after the other.

But the idea is that the rules executing the java code give time to the rules determining what needs to be executed to come up with the final decision.

In the case I've presented above, as soon as you create your session, you will have an activation (`A1`) for `SomeConditionFalseRule` but the activation will not be executed until you call `fireAllRules()`. If you then insert the necessary facts to make `SomeConditionTrueRule` true, you will have now an activation (`A2`) for it.

At this point, the agenda will look like this: `| A1 | A2 |`.

When calling `fireAllRules()`, Drools will pick the activation in the agenda with the higher salience (by default, rules have a `salience` of 0). In this case, `A2` will be picked and executed.

The execution of `A2` will insert a new Fact that will make `A1` invalid and it will create a new activation (`A3`) for `SomeConditionTrueRule`. Drools will then proceed to remove `A1` from the agenda, so the rule `SomeConditionFalseRule` will not be executed.

The agenda after `A2` is executed will look like this: | A3 |

Hope it helps,